# how do I make the independent variables columns and targets into variables X and y

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

how do I make the independent variables columns and targets into variables X and y

#independent columns --> SepalLengthCm, SepalWidthCm, PetalLengthCm, PetalWidthCm
`X = df1.<...>`

#target columns --> species

`y = df1.<...>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following.

```
x = df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]].values
```

Here you use iloc [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), so you take all elements (:) from columns with index [0,1,2,3] then you take the values because iloc returns pandas object.
For target, you can do the following.

```
y = df.iloc[:, [4]].values
```

This dataset is really popular, here you can find a lot of examples exploring and working with it [Iris examples](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arshid/iris-flower-dataset/code?datasetId=17860&sortBy=voteCount).